# Filter and modify array until condition met using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am answering this exercise in FreeCodeCamp here's the instruction
Drop it
Given the array arr, iterate through and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function func returns true when the iterated element is passed through it.

Then return the rest of the array once the condition is satisfied, otherwise, arr should be returned as an empty array.

this is what I have so far. I used the map function to iterate the indexes of array then check if it met the condition of the function parameter inside the map. In this case, the function should return only the numbers less than 3 but I can't get rid of 3 when returning it.

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.map(x => func(x) ? x : "");
}
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3], function(n) {return n < 3; }));
```

Comment: `map` is the wrong tool here, it always creates an array of the same length as the input. Do not use it. Setting an entry to `""` is not the same as dropping it.

Comment: Also the goal is not to get rid of the 3 in your example invocation.

Comment: The function given returns true on the first element, so no entries should be dropped from the array?  Remove element starting from 0 until func returns true (also element 0, so remove no elements)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over a boolean value and keep a `true` value for the rest of the array for filtering.

Source of data/results: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/drop-it

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.filter((b => v => b ||= func(v))(false));
}

console.log(...dropElements([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n < 3; }));       // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(...dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) { return n >= 3; }));   // [3, 4]
console.log(...dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) { return n === 1; }));  // [1, 0, 1]
console.log(...dropElements([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n > 0; }));       // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(...dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) { return n > 5; }));    // []
console.log(...dropElements([1, 2, 3, 7, 4], function(n) { return n > 3; })); // [7, 4]
console.log(...dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) { return n > 2; })); // [3, 9, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest using a filter, which returns another array:

```js
function dropElements(arr) {
  return arr.filter(x => x < 3);
}

const someArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(dropElements(someArray)); // [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  arr.some(function(ele, index) {
    if (func(ele)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      arr.shift();
      return false;
    }
  });
  return arr;
}
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n >= 3
}));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: @AztecCodes A code only answer is an answer. Please do not select "Recommend Deletion" from Low Quality Answers reviews.

Comment: @Imran, please test code before submitting it. The expected result is [3, 4], not [2, 3, 4]. Modifying the array while `some` is running is bad news.

Answer (score 0):

It says "remove elements" so I'm gonna mutate the array that was passed in.

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  while (arr.length && !func(arr[0])) {
    arr.splice(0, 1);
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3], function(n) {return n < 3; }));
```

Comment: OP also says `In this case, the function should return only the numbers less than 3 but I can't get rid of 3 when returning it.`

Comment: @dippas oh, do I have it backwards?  Should it be `!func(arr[0])` ?  Seems weird.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me also, I went with last statement OP said :)

Comment: I located the [question on freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/drop-it) and my above algorithm (with `!func(arr[0])`) passes